# Pandas DataFrame - Extract string between two strings and include the first delimiter

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, extract

I've the following strings in column on a dataframe:

```
"LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt"
"DRAFT-1-FILENAME-ADBCD.txt"
```

And I want to extract everything that is between the word FILE and the ".". But I want to include the first delimiter. Basically I am trying to return the following result:

```
"FILE-ABC"
"FILENAME-ABCD"
```

For that I am using the script below:

```
df['field'] = df.string_value.str.extract('FILE/(.w+)')
```

But I am not able to return the desired information (always getting NA).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you certain all fields will end in `.txt` ?

Comment: Hi @Celius, yes all values it ends witj .txt

Comment: That data format is a bit strange, is a DataFrame really the right choice for this?

Comment: If you have just the two strings above, you could do it like that, but I assume you're looking for something that is more generalized:  "LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt".strip("LOCATION").strip(".txt")

Comment: That wouldn't work for the second string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can accomplish this all within the regex without having to use string slicing.

```
df['field'] = df.string_value.str.extract('(FILE.*(?=.txt))')
```

- FILE is the what we begin the match on
- .* grabs any number of characters
- (?=) is a lookahead assertion that matches without
  consuming.

Handy regex tool https://pythex.org/

Comment: thanks for introducing to https://pythex.org/

Answer (score 2):

If the strings will always end in `.txt` then you can try with the following:

```
df['field'] = df['string_value'].str.extract('(FILE.*)')[0].str[:-4]
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
text = ["LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt","DRAFT-1-FILENAME-ADBCD.txt"]
data = {'index':[0,1],'string_value':text}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['field'] = df['string_value'].str.extract('(FILE.*)')[0].str[:-4]
```

Output:

```
   index                string_value           field
0      0      LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt        FILE-ABC
1      1  DRAFT-1-FILENAME-ADBCD.txt  FILENAME-ADBCD
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit ALollz I deleted my anwer until I had that worked out :P

Answer (score 2):

You can make a capturing group that captures from (including) `'FILE'` greedily to the last period. Or you can make it not greedy so it stops at the first `.` after FILE.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'string_value': ["LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt", "DRAFT-1-FILENAME-ADBCD.txt",
                                    "BADFILENAME.foo.txt"]})

df['field_greedy'] = df['string_value'].str.extract('(FILE.*)\.')
df['field_not_greedy'] = df['string_value'].str.extract('(FILE.*?)\.')
```

---

```
print(df)
                 string_value    field_greedy field_not_greedy
0      LOCATION: FILE-ABC.txt        FILE-ABC         FILE-ABC
1  DRAFT-1-FILENAME-ADBCD.txt  FILENAME-ADBCD   FILENAME-ADBCD
2         BADFILENAME.foo.txt    FILENAME.foo         FILENAME
```